# Incorrect width and height after rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, resize, frame, screen-rotation

I have to draw a menu with section which have to supports rotate only on iPad.

When I start application first time on device everything is fine even if the device is in portrait or landscape mode.

After the rotation I receive wrong size for the view wich contain the cells.

```
 -(void)buildMenu:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientationValue{
        CGFloat padding    = 1;
        CGFloat widthCell  = 0;
        CGFloat heightCell = 0;

        int rowNo = 0;
        int columnsNo = 0;
        int goToNextRow = 0; // used when we draw the menu - start drawing cell to the next row in menu

        if((interfaceOrientationValue == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientationValue == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)){//iPad Landscape - FH only for iPad support rotation

            rowNo = kLandscapeColumns;  //  2
            columnsNo = kLandscapeRows; //  3

            widthCell  = (self.viewMenuArea.frame.size.width/columnsNo-rowNo*padding);
            heightCell = (self.viewMenuArea.frame.size.height/rowNo-padding);

            goToNextRow = columnsNo; // go to the next line/row when we were draq the cell 4.

        }else{//iPad || iPhone - Portrait
            rowNo = kPortraitRows; //2
            columnsNo = kPortraitColumns; //3

            widthCell  = (self.viewMenuArea.frame.size.width/rowNo-padding);
            heightCell = (self.viewMenuArea.frame.size.height/columnsNo-padding);

            goToNextRow = rowNo; // go to the next line/row when we were draq the cell 3.
        }

        //Draw Menu Cells
        CGFloat x = 0;
        CGFloat y = 0;
        int itemsCount  = 1;

        for(int i=0; i<self.dataSource.count; i++){
             [FHMenuCell buildMenuCell_initWithTitle:[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:i] isDisabled:NO xOrigin:x yOrigin:y width:widthCell height:heightCell pendingItems:0 owner:self container:self.viewMenuArea delegate:self tag:i];

            if (itemsCount % goToNextRow == 0){
                y += heightCell + padding;
                x = 0;
            }else{
                x += widthCell+padding;
            }

            itemsCount++;
        }
    }
```

I call this methods in `viewwillappear` and after when user rotate the device in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`.

I added a printscreen with the self.viewMenuArea in xib.
[image]

Any advice regarding the correct frame of the view which contain the cells (`self.viewMenuArea`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, you've mixed such enums as UIDeviceOrientation and UIInterfaceOrientation.
First of all, try to change

```
    if((interfaceOrientationValue == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientationValue == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)){
```

to

```
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientationValue)) {
```

You should also pay attention to the autoresizing masks/ autolayout constraints set in your XIB/storyboard, it may affect the frame of your `viewMenuArea`. Just to be sure that those won't affect your viewMenuArea, remove all of them from that view in XIB/storyboard and try again. the view's frame shouldn't change.

Other than that, it's a good practice to separate view from viewController and implement all the layout stuff in its `layoutSubviews' method.

Comment: I checked viewMenuArea in the XIB and it's ok.I loged the frame for self.viewMenuArea and when I rotate the device in buildMenu on the correct orientation I have the old frame (e.g if I was in portrait and I rotated the device in landscape the frame for self.MenuArea is the same as in portrai orientation). If I rotate again the frame for it is the correct frame from landscape... any advice please ?

Comment: the code that you provided doesn't change the self.viewMenuArea's frame. So please try looking for 'viewMenuArea.frame =' somewhere in your project if it's not changed by autoresizing mask or autolayout introduced in your xib

Comment: I solved by moving the call function from didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation to willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation .